# How can I get a snapshot of a website that can serve as an evidence of its current state?

Tags: website

How can I get a snapshot of a website that can serve as an evidence of its current state?

There is a website that requires authentication that I want to take a snapshot of it as a proof that the site did list my information at this time. So in case they take down my info, I could say I have a proof that they did have my info there before they removed it.

I could take a screenshot of it but it wouldn't be a solid evidence because screenshot image could be said to be photoshop'ed.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: DO you need this for legal reasons, or for something else? There's different criteria for either.

Comment: Not for legal reasons at this moment, but if there is something this solid that can be used as legal evidence, then it will be even better.

Comment: Could you not simply PrtScrn the page? Or do you need more than that?

Comment: @LiamMcSherry The OP stated that screenshots could be photoshopped.

Comment: @slhck Anything can be faked these days, anything. It all boils down to credibility as eluded to by RedGrittyBrick.

Comment: @slhck Oops, I just skimmed.

Answer (score 5):

Pay a lawyer to use your credentials and take a screenshot and write a letter confirming that the details were present on that website at that time.

The legal arrangements in some countries define a "notary public" role who may be able to provide this sort of service.