# Print attachments of an email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, printing, thunderbird

I need to print an e-mail for legal reasons (it's evidence). There are 12 attachments on it, but when printed separately they don't seem to belong to the e-mail.

I need to print the e-mail, with header, and then each attachment on its own page, with a header containing its file-name or other e-mail related info so it is clear the attachment is part of the e-mail.

Can Outlook do this? If not, can other well-known e-mail client do it? It has to look legit. Or the only way to do it is to load the e-mail on Word and make a "mock-up" of it? *shivers*

Comment: Never heard of such functionality. Email attachment purpose is usually to preserve 100% of attachment integrity without alteration.

Comment: Replace `I need to print the e-mail, with header, and then each attachment on its own page, with a header containing its file-name or other e-mail related info so it is clear the attachment is part of the e-mail.` with I `THINK` I need to print the e-mail, with header, and then each attachment on its own page, with a header containing its file-name or other e-mail related info so it is clear the attachment is part of the e-mail. - What does the attorney in the case have to say?

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm a Brazilian, and here the court system is SLOW. By slow I mean that even simple cases, like a traffic ticket claim, can go on for more than a year. More complex cases, like those involving children and family, take **years**. For example, in cases like this, it is not uncommon for the child to reach 18 years old before the litigation is over. So if there is any gap in your argument, the defendant may (will) use it to buy more time. **Any** gap. So we must close every possible way out.

Comment: @joeqwerty  If the defendant says I "injected" the attachment into the e-mail message, the absence of any header will make the judge more keen to accept this claim - the e-mail provider will be called to verify message authenticity; this will take ages. Also, here in Brazil, electronic evidence like e-mail wasn't accepted in court until recently. It is a new thing, the judges have no techonological expertise and may not even use e-mail themselves. What may seem like a no-brainer to us, power users, to them is rocket science. And finally, this is an attorney-less case, because the value is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook doesn't have the functionality you are looking for. It simply opens the attachments in  the default program for each attachment, and prints them.

You would need to use a custom solution to achieve what you are looking for, but this won't provide much proof because it is open for you to manipulate it.

I'm not sure if anyone on SuperUser will have the legal expertise to give you a perfect answer. However, if you take a screenshot of the email showing the attachments on it, it will add a *bit* more credibility to your argument.

You could also consider having a witness testify that the attachments you printed are authentic. Apparently in some countries certain types of lawyers provide this service - they are called "notary public" or "public notaries". Also see [this answer.](https://superuser.com/a/504501/231678)